# Index of All columns Whose Particular rows Satisfies Given Condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Suppose we have a dataframe of N rows and m columns. For each column, I want to find the first index for which a condition is satisfied.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((50,5)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

For each column, I can do

```
df[df['A']<0.5].index[0]
```

to find the first row for that column. I was wondering if there is a way to get it for all columns without for loop?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `df[df<0.5].fillna(method= 'bfill').iloc[0]`? Or do you want to employ one threshold for each column?

Comment: Also, could you set any seed value `np.random.seed(1)` to your question so that it is easier to replicate your problem?

Comment: @xicocaio it did not work. Answer below did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argmax`

```
>>> (df.to_numpy() < 0.5).argmax(axis=0)
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```